Error while creating a distributor database in the process of SQL Server replication. Access Denied
I've got below error while creating distributor database (SQL Server replication process):

Configure Distribution Wizard


An error occurred configuring SQL Server Agent.


RegCreateKeyEx() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.' (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22002)

What should I do to fix this problem?

Check on this:
Just select  “No, I will start the Sql Server Agent manually” instead of “Yes, configure Sql Server Agent to start automatically“ during setting up Distribution.
And make sure you made SQL Server Agent to start automatically from services.msc.
It did solve the error. There'll be no third line displayed at the end of wizard,
error:

after re-setup with option 'No' for SQL Agent, no error

